# Router needs to be released every several minutes

Tags: wireless-networking, router, isp

I'm currently living in a boarding house at the moment and recently my landlord changed our ISP. On the first 2 days, it seems that it has no problems. However yesterday I found that my internet went down and has connectivity issues. I tried to troubleshoot as much as I can and what I found is my wi-fi router needs to be released every time it went down by releasing it manually from LAN config.

The WAN connection is always connected (connection status is not disconnected, has IP, DNS, etc.), however there is no internet access (traffic statistic showed a 0.1KBps ish uplink/downlink rate).

I've tried power cycling the router and also hard reset the router and it seems that it's not the issue. Even changing wi-fi router seems is not the problem. I can only connect to the internet after I release the DHCP connection, and needs to be redone every 3-12 minutes. Opening any websites through google chrome at that time will results in DNS_PROBE_STARTED and DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET.

Is this a problem from the ISP? If so, why can I connect to the internet if I release the DHCP connection? I've been searching for answers the whole day and I ended up

**EDIT**

I can increase my DHCP pool range in my wi-fi router from 150-200 to 2-254, however each room is provided with one wall lan port outlet and we need to provide our own wi-fi router, so I only need 2 IP which is for my PC and my phone.

The router that I used is Tenda N630 v2, as for the internet connection type I believe is fiber. The WAN IP is shared via 192.168.1.x, when I try to enter 192.168.1.1, it has a residential gateway in it. I believe that our internet is distributed via a switch into each room. We have somewhere around 20 room here.

Normally, we plug our connection from wall lan port outlet to wi-fi WAN port, however some people here plug their connection directly to LAN 1 port, then use the wi-fi like normal, or use LAN 2 port if they use a PC.

I release my DHCP lease from my local wi-fi router configuration (192.168.17.1), which shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS0Ff.png)

Comment: Are you releasing the DHCP lease on the router or your PC?   Also, when I was talking about increasing the range of DHCP IP's, I was talking about doing it on the ISP provided router.

Comment: Can you provide a traceroute from your router to somewhere external - like Google?   I wonder if part of your problem is an IP address conflict combined with NAT issues - maybe when the provider changed so did the router, and with it the IP's.  If both your router and the ISP's router are configured to use the same subnet I can see how this can cause issues.

Comment: when you're saying releasing on PC do you mean by cmd using ipconfig /release? I've done both from PC and from the wireless router. I don't have the authorization to the ISP provided router, sorry. Also, I've added the tracert results.

Comment: You said in your original post that "I can only connect to the internet after I release the DHCP connection" and I'm trying to ascertain where you are doing this.

Comment: I'm doing it inside my local wifi router configuration (192.168.17.1)

Comment: This sounds very much like the ISP router is incorrectly configured and does not have a large enough dhcp range, or its a crap router which can t handle the number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: That would make sense i think, since this happened after the ISP technician came. I will try to contact the ISP and follow up the situation. Thank you for your help @davidgo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you either have more then 1 DHCP server on the LAN or to many clients for the router to handle. (Can you increase the number of IP addresses in the DHCP pool)?

It sounds unlikely that the problem is ISP related if the issue is with DHCP which is typically handled by the router and beyond the control of the ISP.

For better answers you should add the router model, connectivity type (cable? ADSL? Vdsl? Fibre?), The number of users, and also if you are changing DHCP on the computer or router.

Comment: I have added some information that might be useful. thank you for your help.

Comment: It was indeed the ISP router, I've talked with the technician and they will change the router, if this still happen, I will be keeping the old ISP. thank you for your help.